# How to recognize only one parameter - htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect when has only one parameter, for example:
for the path /game/amazing the user are gonna play the game called amazing, if the user goes to /game/category/action, the user goes to the category action and is gonna see all the action games.
How to do this?

```
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+) play.php?play=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^/]+) play.php?category=$1&show=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use anchor `$` in your patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/?$ play.php?play=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ play.php?genre=$1&show=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but the name category is not the same, sometimes change to game/cate/action, that's why i need two parameters for the htaccess.

Comment: So what should be internal URI for `/game/cate/action`?

Comment: /game/category/action
    /game/cate/action

Sometimes, i'm gonna change to genre too:
    /game/genre/action

Comment: this work for the 2 parameters, but how about the one parameter? how do i put then together with one and two parameters?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+) play.php?play=$1 [L,QSA]`

`RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^/]+) play.php?genre=$1&show=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ play.php?genre=$1&show=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`